# MvvmCross plugin for setting up Alarms

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I want to write a cross mobile platform app that sets up the alarm by specifying the required parameters like Date and Time. I just want to set up only one time and not repeatedly.
I was unable to find any readily available plugin in mvvmcross or in Xamarin ?

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no existing plugin within MVVMCross, you may want to write your own plugin. You can find the documentation here:

https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/MvvmCross-plugins

Because you'd like to specify a few parameters, you'd want to see the following section:

https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/MvvmCross-plugins#writing-a-configurable-plugin

Overall this is what you might do:

**General Interface**

```
public interface IAlarm
{
    void SetupAlarm(); 
}

public class PluginLoader
    : IMvxPluginLoader
{
    public static readonly PluginLoader Instance = new PluginLoader();

    public void EnsureLoaded()
    {
        var manager = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxPluginManager>();
        manager.EnsurePlatformAdaptionLoaded<PluginLoader>();
    }
}
```

**Android Implementation**

```
public class DroidAlarmConfiguration 
    : IMvxPluginConfiguration
{
    public AlarmLength { get; set;}
}

public class DroidAlarm : IAlarm
{
    public TimeSpan AlarmLength { get; set; }

    public void SetupAlarm()
    {
        //ALARM IMPLEMENTATION HERE. NOTE THIS IS SOME JAVA SYNTAX!!!!
        var globals = Mvx.Resolve<Cirrious.CrossCore.Droid.IMvxAndroidGlobals>();
        var alarm = globals.ApplicationContext
                              .GetSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE)
                              as AlarmManager;

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

        alarm.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
        alarmLength, alarmIntent);
    }
}

public class Plugin
    : IMvxPlugin
{
private _alarmLength = **Your Value Here**;

public void Configure(IMvxPluginConfiguration configuration)
{
    if (configuration == null)
        return;

    var droidConfiguration = (DroidAlarmConfiguration)configuration;
    _alarmLength = droidConfiguration.AlarmLength;
}

public void Load()
{
      var instance = new DroidAlarm();
      instance.AlarmLength = _AlarmLength;
    Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IAlarm>(instance);
}
}
```

**Setup.cs** - To set the values in one core place for all android/ios/windows

```
protected override IMvxPluginConfiguration GetPluginConfiguration(Type plugin)
{
    if (plugin == typeof(Yours.Alarm.Droid.Plugin))
    {
        return new Yours.Alarm.Droid.DroidAlarmConfiguration()
        {
            AlarmLength = **YOUR VALUE HERE**
        };
    }

    return null;
}
```

You would then follow the same Droid step for iOS and Windows Phone. I hope this helps!